# linphone-sdk compilation error - Could not find a support sound driver API

Tags: centos, centos7, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am trying to compile linphone-sdk on Centos 7.8 and got the following error.

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindBV16.cmake:40 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:190 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:327 (message):
  Could not find a support sound driver API.  Use -DENABLE_SOUND=NO if you
  don't care about having sound.
```

After that, I did a

```
cmake -DENABLE_SOUND=NO ..
```

and rebuilt

```
cmake --build .
```

but still got the same error.  Any idea?

The system has the alsa-lib installed

```
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.1.6-1.el7.x86_64
alsa-firmware-1.0.28-2.el7.noarch
alsa-lib-1.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
alsa-utils-1.1.8-2.el7.x86_64
alsa-tools-firmware-1.1.0-1.el7.x86_64
```

Thanks

Comment: Same here... did you ever manage to get this solved? I added quite a lot of -dev packages, to no avail...